# Ambiguous functions in multiple protocol extensions?

Tags: swift, generics, swift2, protocols, protocol-extension

I have multiple protocols that have the same function name. Some protocols have associated types, where I can't figure out how to call the functions as I do in non-generic protocols. I get the error: `Protocol 'MyProtocol1' can only be used as a generic contraint because it has Self or associated type requirements`

Here's what I'm trying to do:

```
protocol Serviceable {
   associatedtype DataType
   func get(handler: ([DataType] -> Void)?)
}

struct PostService: Serviceable {
   func get(handler: ([String] -> Void)? = nil) {
      print("Do something...")
   }
}

protocol MyProtocol1: class {
   associatedtype ServiceType: Serviceable
   var service: ServiceType { get }
}

extension MyProtocol1 {
   func didLoad(delegate: Self) {
      print("MyProtocol1.didLoad()")
   }
}

protocol MyProtocol2: class {

}

extension MyProtocol2 {
   func didLoad(delegate: MyProtocol2) {
      print("MyProtocol2.didLoad()")
   }
}

class MyViewController: UIViewController, MyProtocol1, MyProtocol2 {
   let service = PostService()

   override func viewDidLoad() {
      super.viewDidLoad()
      didLoad(self as MyProtocol1) // Error here: Protocol 'MyProtocol1' can only be used as a generic contraint because it has Self or associated type requirements
      didLoad(self as MyProtocol2)
   }
}
```

How can I specifically call the function from a generic protocol extension?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's simple to achieve by turning the protocol into a generic (see below), or by creating a [type eraser](http://robnapier.net/erasure) for these protocols, but this very strongly suggests that you have a design problem and you should redesign your classes and/or extensions. A collision like this suggests strongly that `MyStruct` is doing too many things itself because it's being pulled in multiple directions by `MyProtocol1` and `MyProtocol2`. There should likely be two objects here instead. (Composition rather than inheritance.)

```
class MyStruct: MyProtocol1, MyProtocol2 {
    let service = PostService()

    func prot1Load<T: MyProtocol1>(t: T) {
        t.didLoad()
    }

    func prot2Load<T: MyProtocol2>(t: T) {
        t.didLoad()
    }
    init() {
        prot1Load(self)
        prot2Load(self)
    }
}
```

To your particular example in the comments, I would use composition rather than inheritance. You're treating protocols like multiple-inheritance, which is almost never right. Instead compose out of things that conform to a protocol.

```
protocol LoadProviding {
    func load()
}

struct MyLoader1: LoadProviding {
    func load() {
        print("MyLoader1.didLoad()")
    }
}

struct MyLoader2: LoadProviding {
    func load() {
        print("MyLoader2.didLoad()")
    }
}

protocol Loader {
    var loaders: [LoadProviding] { get }
}

extension Loader {
    func loadAll() {
        for loader in loaders {
            loader.load()
        }
    }
}

class MyStruct: Loader {
    let service = PostService()
    let loaders: [LoadProviding] = [MyLoader1(), MyLoader2()]

    init() {
        loadAll()
    }
}
```

Of course you don't really have to have `LoadProviding` be a full struct. It could just be a function if that's all you need:

```
typealias LoadProviding = () -> Void

func myLoader1() {
    print("MyLoader1.didLoad()")
}

func myLoader2() {
    print("MyLoader2.didLoad()")
}

protocol Loader {
    var loaders: [LoadProviding] { get }
}

extension Loader {
    func loadAll() {
        for loader in loaders {
            loader()
        }
    }
}

class MyStruct: Loader {
    let service = PostService()
    let loaders: [LoadProviding] = [myLoader1, myLoader2]

    init() {
        loadAll()
    }
}
```

If you have time to wade through a video on the subject, you may be interested in the [Beyond Crusty: Real World Protocols](http://www.thedotpost.com/2016/01/rob-napier-beyond-crusty-real-world-protocols) talk from dotSwift. It's about this and similar problems.

Comment: Indeed it smells. I'm trying to achieve multiple inheritance using protocol extensions. For example, in the `viewDidLoad` of my `UIViewController`, I'd like to execute every `didLoad` function of each of my protocols.

Comment: Then you should have a property like `let loader: [Loader]` that contains the various initializations you need.

Comment: I would probably think more deeply about the names here to make them match current Swift style guidelines, but the above is still how I would certainly attack it.

Comment: Brilliant dotSwift talk! Thank you!! Generics are weak in Swift :(, hopefully it rounds out in v3.